# SetInterval frozen without error message, and script responding to some listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created a simple extension that works as a countdown with a setTimer, it's suppose to be constantly running, doing his action, and then restarting itself. I displayed the countdown as the badge text of my extension, and I now have it frozen at 56:18 (countdown starts from 59:59 - the timer froze one time before, around 43 minutes so the time seems to be random) after completing his first row

I have a listener on update, that will check the badge text, and if it's empty, starts the timer, otherwise send a message in the console. I'm currently receiving messages in the console if I refresh a page

This script is in the background Script, I haven't made it persistent (don't know the use for it...) and I had Chrome in the background, while I was working on Excel.

Here's the code of my countdown:

```
var DelaiProtect = 5
var Countdowntimer = 60
function Countdown() {
countDownDate = new Date().getTime()+(Countdowntimer*60*1000+5);
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  if(seconds < 10 && seconds >= 0) {
      seconds = "0"+Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  }
  var BadgeCD = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  console.log("Countdown : "+ days + " jours "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds)
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(BadgeCD)});
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: '#336699'});
  chrome.tabs.query({url: 'http://localhost:4848/sense/app/*'}, foundTabs => {
    if (foundTabs.length >= 1) {    
    }
    else {
        console.log("STOP plus d'onglets QlikSense")
        clearInterval(x);
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: ""});
    }
  });
    var DepuisQd = now - lastUseQlik
if (distance < 1 && DepuisQd > (1000*DelaiProtect*60)) {
            clearInterval(x);
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "..."});
            chrome.tabs.query({url: 'http://localhost:4848/sense/app/*'}, foundTabs => {
            if (foundTabs && foundTabs.length) {
                foundTabs.forEach(tab => chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id));
                console.log("chargement effectué ! "+foundTabs.length)  
            }
        });
        Countdown();
        }
if (distance < (1000*60*DelaiProtect) && (distance+DepuisQd) < (1000*DelaiProtect*60)) {
    var minutes2 = Math.floor((((1000*DelaiProtect*60)-DepuisQd) % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds2 = Math.floor((((1000*DelaiProtect*60)-DepuisQd) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    if(seconds2 < 10 && seconds2 >= 0) {
        var seconds2 = "0" + Math.floor((((1000*DelaiProtect*60)-DepuisQd) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    }
    var BadgeCD2 = minutes2+":"+seconds2;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: String(BadgeCD2)});
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: '#FF0000'});   
    }
}, 1000);
};
```

Thanks for your help, as I have no idea of where to look at first...

Comment: the timer freezes at 56:18?

Comment: The timer freezes at a random time (last time it was 43:xx don't remember the seconds). It happened both time while I was doing other stuff than just browsing chrome on my computer

Comment: Without `"persistent": true` in manifest.json your background script will be automatically terminated after 5 seconds of inactivity (no messages, for example). So you need to add it.

Comment: Oh ok, so I just need to make it persistent, and it shouldn't happen again ? But wasn't it supposed to be constantly active with a setInterval every second ?

Comment: I've put it as persistent, and I added an alarm every minute, that will check if the countdown is stuck or not, and if it is reset it. I'll see if it works